# Wordpress Child Theme vs Copying existing theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, updates

I'm new to WordPress but realize that themes can be updated which will cause you to loose any customization you have made.

For the site I'm working on at the moment, I have copied the theme, by changing it's folder name & the name at the top of the `style.css` in the comments. I then uploaded it to the server.
Since then I have learnt that you can make child themes.

Which is better practice, is their any advantages or disadvantages to either approach?  Is it possible that the changes which I have made to my copied theme will get over ridden? The only major changes I have made to my copied theme have been to the `style.css` & `header.php`.

Comment: While we make changes in parent theme,if we try to upgrade,all the custom style ll reset.The best practice is to create a child theme and activate that child theme.

Comment: what if you copy the parent theme & change it's name, will the changes be made on upgrade then?

Comment: Child theme is much more manageable.You can keep Only required files,also  can access all the parent theme functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only making minor changes, then you should use a child theme. This has several advantages:

- You get free updates whenever the parent theme is updated. This includes security updates, which could be very important.
- Your code base will be *much* more manageable.
- You will also find it easier to apply your alterations to other themes.

Comment: Thank you, it seems child themes are better than copying a theme.  But will a coppied theme get it's changes overridden in an update or are updates not going to happen for it as I've changed the name

Comment: @rossmc If you change the name, you won't get any updates. If you don't change the name, any changes you make will be lost when the theme is updated.